# ExtJS Store to POST, GET, PUT and DELETE

Tags: extjs, extjs7

Is there any guide or sample code that show how to do POST, GET, PUT and DELETE from ExtJS Store to Elasticsearch or any related database?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [rest proxy](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Rest.html) so simple access to [save](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.data.Model.html#method-save) (POST/PUT), get and [destroy](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.data.Model.html#method-destroy) (DELETE) methods.

[Full youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fj5Le-2u8Qc)

Comment: Can I check with you how can I use the AjaxProxy?

Comment: You can use AjaxProxy too. For set paths to your endpoint use api property
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.html#cfg-api